# Can I backup my virtual machine while it is suspended instead of turned off? [VMWare]

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, vmware-fusion

In the [online documentation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2006202) it is "advised" to completely turn off a virtual machine before creating a backup of the folder with all the VM files in it.

However, I have a machine where a complete shut down would cause me a lot of work to restart all the services after a shutdown (I spare you the reasons why).

What sort of issues could I experience if I did not completely power the VM down before making a backup? Has anyone tried this before themselves?

I know that in suspended state, VMWare just makes a full memory dump to a file (you can see it appear in the folder, which you include in your backup), so I don't see what would cause an issue when backing up in suspended state.

Comment: If you quasi the disk this can be done.  However, backing up just the virtual HDD while the vm is turned on, won’t working (at least without quasi the disk)

Comment: Why don't you try to copy the entire folder and see? I would suggest to name the folder on the target exactly as on the source computer, with same disk drive-letter and same folder-name.

Comment: If you back up a suspended machine, you will be able to resume from the restored back-up, but you won't be able to depend on retrieving files from the virtual disc (eg using 7-Zip), as any files open at the time of suspension cannot be assumed to be fully written to disc. Cold-starting the suspended VM will likewise be liable to corrupt previously open files. You may also experience difficulties if you try to resume on different hardware. But a simple restore and resume on the same machine will work reliably and you can then shut down to ensure the integrity if the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential issue with backing up a suspended VM is that you won't be able to resume it if the backup is restored to a different host. (That might happen because you upgraded to a new physical machine, or maybe your old physical machine catastrophically failed, forcing you to use backups.)

For example, the VM might be suspended and then resumed on hosts with different CPU or 3D-acceleration capabilities.  If this happens, VMware Workstation might warn you and let you resume anyway, but in cases of more severe incompatibility, it won't let you resume at all, forcing you to discard the suspend state (the VM equivalent of yanking the power cord on a physical machine), losing any work that wasn't saved to the virtual disks.

Other possible issues would be if the VM is actively doing anything with external resources: accessing network file systems, accessing raw physical disks, accessing shared folders, etc., but you'd potentially have issues with those things from using suspend/resume at all.